# Android auto backup - how to know when the last backup was made?

Tags: android, backup

I am using the Android AutoBackup feature in my app. These are my manifest settings.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
android:fullBackupOnly="true"
```

Is there a way to know when the last backup for my app was made?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I have found says this:

[schedule](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#BackupSchedule)

[Backup documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)

Frequency   Apps must issue a request when there is data that is ready to be backed up. Requests from multiple apps are batched and executed every few hours.   Backups happen automatically roughly once a day.

Also, it looks like if you write your own agent you can register for backup or restore events.

[events](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/BackupAgent#onQuotaExceeded(long,%20long))

also, one last thing, when you implement the events it looks like backup gives access to the date of the last backup.   As far as I can see, a customs agent gets you the info you need with some coding

[examples](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup#java)